react function that sets default props for a component and make them optional or removed
I have the following component and props:

export type DefaultSaveTreeContentFormProps<C extends TreeContent> = {
  treeRef: RefObject<TreeRef<C, TreeNodeData<C>>>;
  mutation: UseMutationResult<C, Error, SaveTreeContentSchemaType>;
  type: TreeContentType;
  onSuccess: (res: C) => void;
};

export function DefaultSaveTreeContentForm<C extends TreeContent>({
  treeRef,
  mutation,
  type,
  onSuccess: onSuccessFromProps,
}: DefaultSaveTreeContentFormProps<C>) {}

In my another component, one of its prop is:
export type TreeForms<C extends TreeContent> = {
  [K in TreeContentType[number]]: {
    save: React.ComponentType<{
      treeRef: React.RefObject<TreeRef<C, TreeNodeData<C>>>;
      onSuccess: (res: C) => void;
    }>;
  };
};


So as save I need to pass the component with only two props. I wrote the following function to convert 4 prop component to 2-prop component:
export function setAndRemoveProps<T extends {}>(
  Component: ComponentType<T>,
  defaultProps: Partial<T>
): ComponentType<Omit<T, keyof typeof defaultProps>> {
  const WrappedComponent = (props: Omit<T, keyof typeof defaultProps>) => {
    return <Component {...defaultProps} {...(props as T)} />;
  };

  WrappedComponent.displayName = `withDefaultProps(${Component.displayName || Component.name || 'Component'})`;

  return WrappedComponent;
}

but then when I use it:
 forms={{
          [TreeContentType.FOLDER]: {
            save: setAndRemoveProps(DefaultSaveTreeContentForm, {
              mutation: mutationSaveContent,
              type: TreeContentType.FOLDER,
            }),
          },
        }}


I have an error:
Type 'ComponentType<Omit<DefaultSaveTreeContentFormProps<TreeContent>, keyof DefaultSaveTreeContentFormProps<TreeContent>>>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentType<{ treeRef: RefObject<TreeRef<TreeContent, TreeNodeData<TreeContent>>>; onSuccess: (res: TreeContent) => void; }>'.

 Type 'Readonly<Omit<DefaultSaveTreeContentFormProps<TreeContent>, keyof DefaultSaveTreeContentFormProps<TreeContent>>>' is missing the following properties from type 'Readonly<{ treeRef: RefObject<TreeRef<TreeContent, TreeNodeData<TreeContent>>>; onSuccess: (res: TreeContent) => void; }>': treeRef, onSuccess

Howw to fix that?
